# Counting Cumulative Occurrences and Plotting Over Time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a  sample dataframe that looks like:

```
Time              Type
2019-12-09 04:50  Exists
2019-12-08 01:20  Does Not Exist
2019-12-08 03:32  Exists
2019-12-07 01:15  APPLES
2019-12-05 04:13  Does Not Exist
```

I want to cumulatively count the number of occurrences of "Exists" and "Does Not Exist", not the Occurrence of "APPLES", and plot those two values versus time.  I have created the Occurrences, as shown below, but the time is not in ascending order.

1. How do I change the time to ascending order, and then plot only "Exists" and "Does Not Exist", just in a scatter-line plot?

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

my_cols = ["Time","Type"]
df = pd.read_csv('occurrences.txt',names = my_cols,sep=';')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time',inplace=True)
df['Occurrence'] = df.groupby("Type").cumcount()
```

Comment: How should the plot look like? two seperate lines, one for exists and one for not exist?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going for: Time on X-axis, Cumulative Occurrence on Y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Filter your df first and `sort_values`:

```
new = df.loc[df['Type'].ne("APPLES")].sort_values(["Type","Time"])

new["occurance"] = new.groupby("Type").cumcount()
new.set_index("Time").groupby('Type')['occurance'].plot(legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]